# How to run jnlp ib Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java

When I try to install icedtea, and run fule using the command `/usr/bin/jawaws myfile.jlnp`, I got `Unable to use Firefox's proxy settings. Using "DIRECT" as proxy type. Codebase matches codebase manifest attribute, and application is signed. Continuing. See: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/… for details`

What is a new and correct way to run jnlp files?